Python GUI runs separate scripts through subprocess calls, but doesn't work when packaged as .exe
I have an interface I've created called interface.py that runs a script based on the press of a button...
def submit_action(selected_item):
    values = list(item_to_value[selected_item])
    selected_month = month_var.get()
    
    # Check the state of the checkboxes and assign values
    invoice_value = "1" if invoice_var.get() else "0"
    loader_value = "1" if loader_var.get() else "0"

    # Append the checkbox values to the values list
    values.append(invoice_value)
    values.append(loader_value)
    values.append(selected_month)  # Append the selected month

    if selected_item in ["Type 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]:
        subprocess.run(["py", "gen_simple_management_fee.py"] + values)
    elif selected_item in ["Type 2", "Item 2", "Item 3"]:
        subprocess.run(["py", "gen_no_split_variant_2.py"] + values)
    elif selected_item in ["Type 3", "Item 5"]:
        subprocess.run(["py", "gen_fixed_split.py"] + values)
    elif selected_item in ["Type 4", "Item 5"]:
        subprocess.run(["py", "gen_daily_validations.py"] + values)    
    elif selected_item in ["Type 5", "Type 6"]:
        subprocess.run(["py", "gen_variable_split.py"] + values)
    elif selected_item in ["Type 7", "Type 8"]:
        subprocess.run(["py", "gen_variable_split_variant_2.py"] + values)
    elif selected_item in ["Type 9", "Type 10"]:
        subprocess.run(["py", "gen_no_split.py"] + values)


I also send a set of values across to the other scripts using a list that gets sent along with the subprocess call:
item_to_value = {
    "Type 1": ("Information 1", "information 2", "placeholder", "placeholder", "placeholder", "placeholder"),
    "Type 2": ("Information 1", "Information 2", "placeholder", "placeholder", "placeholder", "placeholder"),

...


The script gets run, drawing on the subprocess information passed:
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image

corresponding_value = sys.argv[1]
print(f"Running with corresponding value: {corresponding_value}")

billing_project_name = sys.argv[6]
selected_month = sys.argv[-1]
selected_month = str(selected_month)

...

When I try to package this as an .exe through pyinstaller, I either get the issue that the main interface.py file re-runs and displays another iteration of the gui, or the exe can't find the various scripts to run.
How can I make this work as an executable file? I want to avoid having to re-jig the code to run as multiprocessing instead of subprocess - unless it's the only way...
If there's a way to create an entrypoint script that runs the interface.py, then passes the correct variables and script to run, how would I do that? Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Did you include those scripts into the generated executable?  Also it is better to use the embedded Python executable instead of py.

The files are present in the .spec file when I generate the .exe. I think the issue is related to how subprocess calls work - it reruns the initial script instead of locating and running the appropriate script. Maybe I'm referencing the files improperly?

You may need to get the actual paths of those scripts instead of using relative paths, see PyInstaller Run-time Information.

If the paths are all in the same directory at the time of creating the .exe, can you give me an example of how I would define the paths directly? I appreciate the responses

The link I posted in my past comment has example.

Hello @intrepid, could you please provide a minimum reproducible example?

Hi @PaulCreusy, I appreciate the response - I resolved the issue by putting the scripts directly under the conditional instead of figuring out why the subprocess.run() statements weren't working.
